# Setting focus on shopping cart line items with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, focus, directive

I've got a modal used to display the line items in my shopping cart. In this shopping cart modal, I display each item, with a quantity input box, on separate rows. Each time a new item is added to the shopping cart, the modal 
opens with the most recently added item at the top. I'd like to have the focus appear in the quantity input box for the most recently added item.

I've found a good example of how to have angularjs set the focus on a specific item by creating a custom directive and adding the 'focus-me' directive to my input box. The problem that I'm having is that the focus is staying 
with the first item added to cart. Here's my html:

```
<div id="shoppingCart" ng-show="cartItems.length > 0" ng-repeat="scItem in cartItems track by $index ">
<div id="shoppingCartItems">
    <fieldset >
        <div class="shoppingCartItem">
            <div id="scCol1">
                <div class="lineItemDetail">
                    <strong>Item #{{ scItem.lineId }}</strong>
                </div>
                <img src="{{ scItem.imageUrl }}">
            </div>
            <div id="scCol2">
                <div class="lineItemDetail">
                    <strong>Qty:</strong>
                    <span>
                        <!-- Put the focus on the qty box if the item was just added to cart -->
                        <input type="text" 
                        name="qty_{{$index}}" 
                        maxlength="7" 
                        size="4" 
                        focus-me="true" 
                        ng-keypress="shoppingCartKeyCheck($event)" 
                        ng-model="scItem.qty" 
                        ng-blur="validateQty(scItem.lineId)"/>
                    </span>
                    <span id="invalidQuantity" ng-show="scItem.validationMessage" ng-bind-html="$sce.trustAsHtml(scItem.validationMessage)"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="lineItemLink">
                    <a href="" ng-click="removeSelectedProduct(scItem.lineId)" class="removeShoppingCartItemLink">Remove From Cart</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br/>                       
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's my custom directive:

```
app.directive('focusMe', function($timeout) {
return {
    scope: { trigger: '@focusMe' },
    link: function(scope, element) {
        scope.$watch('trigger', function(value) {

            if(value === "true") {
                console.log("its true");

                $timeout(function() {
                    element[0].focus();
                });
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that the focus is set when the first shopping cart item is added and its not getting removed/reset when subsequent items are added. I'm a little stuck as to what I need to do here.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This one should help

```
focus-me="{{$index == 0}}"
```